# Problems while following the instructions of Django official documentation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am following Django official tutorial of **Writing your first Django app, part 1**. There at last para i have to give the following command:

```
q.was_published_recently()
```

And the output should be:

```
True
```

Instead, i have:

```
False
```

Here is my models.py file:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.question_text)

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    class Choice(models.Model):
        question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
        choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

I am guessing may be i am having problem at **timedelta** function. I am not sure though.

N.B.: the exact steps of the documentation are:

```
>>> from polls.models import Question, Choice
>>> Question.objects.all()
[<Question: What's up?>]
>>> Question.objects.filter(id=1)
[<Question: What's up?>]
>>> Question.objects.filter(question_text__startswith='What')
[<Question: What's up?>]


>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> current_year = timezone.now().year
>>> Question.objects.get(pub_date__year=current_year)
<Question: What's up?>

>>> Question.objects.get(id=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
     ...
DoesNotExist: Question matching query does not exist.

>>> Question.objects.get(pk=1)
<Question: What's up?>

>>> q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)

>>> q.was_published_recently()
True
```

Comment: To me the timedelta looks fine.. With timedelta you subtract one day from now. I guess the problem is that ```self.pub_date``` is more old than one day and thats why it correctly outputs ```False```. Please type ```q.pub_date``` on console and have a look what is the value.

Comment: Ok, "q.pub_date" command works fine: "datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 29, 15, 40, 19, tzinfo=<UTC>)"    That means, it is referring to 2 days ago from today. Is it a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the method name I would say that `False` is the correct return value in this case. The method should return `True` if the Question is less old than one day. In your case the pub_date is a date more older than one day so it was not "published recently" so the method returns `False`. If you change your date to now with q.pub_date = timezone.now() and then save with q.save(), q.was_published_recently() should return True for exactly one day.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I have found the problem. It was in the definition of the **was_published_recently()** method. It should be **<=** instead of **>=**.

Here is the redefined method:

```
def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date <= timezone.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Previously, the method was testing if the pub_date is greater or equal than the yesterday which was wrong.

Now, it is testing if the pub_date is less or equal than the yesterday, which is right.

Comment: aehm, no.. according to the method name I would say that your change is not correct. The method should return True if the ```Question``` is less old than one day. With your change it returns True if it is more old than one day. The previous code was correct, just your pub_date was a date more older than one day so it was not "published recently" so the method returned False. If you change your date to now with ```q.pub_date = timezone.now()``` and then save with ```q.save()```, ```q.was_published_recently()``` should return True for exactly one day.

Comment: Thanks. My concepts are clearer now. You should comment it. Than i can accept your answer.